# Using onehot labels and matching dimensions in tensor flow

Tags: python, tensorflow, dimensions

This is my Siamese Network, features are 98 images encoded as numpy ndarray which works fine, labels are 0,1,2,3,4 and i.e. they are converted to onehot using tensorflow later, works fine. The mode is "TRAIN" for now. I am following and editing the code of mnist dataset example of tensorflow. I have 98 images which can be of class 0..4. Everything works fine until logits, its dimension not being the same as my labels is the issue.

```
def siamese_network(features, labels, mode):
    """Model function for Siamese Network"""
    input_layer = tf.reshape(features, [-1, 28, 28, 1])
    conv1 = tf.layers.conv2d(
    inputs=input_layer,
    filters=32,
    kernel_size=[5, 5],
    padding="same",
    activation=tf.nn.relu)

    pool1 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=conv1, pool_size=[2, 2], strides=2)

    conv2 = tf.layers.conv2d(
    inputs=pool1,
    filters=64,
    kernel_size=[5, 5],
    padding="same",
    activation=tf.nn.relu)
    pool2 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=conv2, pool_size=[2, 2], strides=2)

    pool2_flat = tf.reshape(pool2, [-1, 7 * 7 * 64])
    dense = tf.layers.dense(inputs=pool2_flat, units=1024, activation=tf.nn.relu)
    dropout = tf.layers.dropout(
    inputs=dense, rate=0.4, training=mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN)

    logits = tf.layers.dense(inputs=dropout, units=5)
    print(logits)    #gives (294,5)
    predictions = {
    "classes": tf.argmax(input=logits, axis=1),
    "probabilities": tf.nn.softmax(logits, name="softmax_tensor")
    }

    if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.PREDICT:
        return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode, predictions=predictions)


    onehot_labels = tf.one_hot(indices=tf.cast(labels, tf.int32), depth=5)
    print(onehot_labels)    #dimension is (98,5)
    print(logits)            # dimension is (294,5)

    #error in this line,until here everything is fine

    loss = tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy(
    onehot_labels=onehot_labels, logits=logits)
```

The error I got at the loss line is this:-

```
 ValueError: Shapes (294, 5) and (98, 5) are incompatible
```

I tried playing with "pool2_flat = tf.reshape(pool2, [-1, 7 * 7 * 64]) , changing poolsize to [5,5]" and the dimensions of logits started changing to (147,5),(96,5) etc but nothing useful happened, also it cant really be a good solution as the training size will change the dimensions will also change subsequently. Where am I doing wrong? Thank you.

Comment: The `labels` argument of `siamese_network` has a size of 98 instead of 294. That's why `tf.one_hot` produces a tensor of size (98, 5) instead of (294, 5).

Comment: I am giving it the size of 98...Actually the error lies in the maxpooling layers' size or the reshaping size. Cause when I change it the value comes to 96 but not 98.

Comment: What is the size of the `features` argument of `siamese_network`? It would be helpful if you printed the size of the result of each CNN stage.

Comment: The CNN is not working lol, the error occurs before the function is finished, the size of features and labels is 98. Features are ndarray images and labels are 0..4 and are converted to onehot later.

Comment: Can you please tell me how the size of logits is calculated? the size of logits should be equal to onehot_labels.

Comment: You're getting the error when you compute the loss. If you remove the loss computation, you can execute the CNN layers without error and display the size of the tensor produced by each layer. That should help explain why `logits` has the wrong size.

Comment: The return statement in mode=='TRAIN' uses loss as param, what should I do to that whole chunk?

Comment: I'd extract the code from `siamese_network` into a separate script so that you can examine the result of each CNN layer.

Comment: Okay that would be really nice of you!!